# why image saving ($files) inside the database is not working properly with ajax/jquery?

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this html code

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="hidden" name="size" value="100000">
       <div>
         <input type="file" name="image">
       </div>
       <div>
         <input type="text" name="title" >
       </div>
       <div>
         <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload Image" id="btn">
       </div>
   </form>
</div>

<?php  $target = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/' . basename($_FILES['image']['name']); ?>
<input type="hidden" id="fileDir" value="<?php echo $_FILES['image']['name'];?>">
```

and this jquery/ajax (in saveImage.php I have the query to save data in database)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        var imgDir = $('#fileDir').val();
        $.post("saveImage.php", {
            imgDir: imgDir
        })
    })
})
```

at the end i have this to move files

in the database it's saving the past img

when i upload an img for the first time,the directory saves blank in the database , then when i upload second img, the first one is saved inside the database

Comment: This seems like a really weird setup. Why do you have this Ajax code? That alone won't upload a file. Also we can't see the rest of the PHP code which responds to any of this so it's hard to be sure exactly what is going on

Comment: see this as an example https://makitweb.com/how-to-upload-image-file-using-ajax-and-jquery/